# How to build a Nativescript application in Spanish?

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am distributing a mobile app made with nativescript-vue in Spanish language, although i have all my labels and stuff in Spanish I am being rejected by IOS because of the right access modals (access storage, location, etc.) being in English, but this is not something im handling in my own coding.
So my question is: is there any possibility for me to build the whole app in Spanish o maybe there is a way for me to overwrite/customize those access rights modals?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Could you please add the actual message from Appstore review?

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide localized version of the plist key-values for each permission. You could do that through the tool you are using for localization and by using the specific iOS keys.
For example, those are the description you need to provide in the Info.plist file for using localization.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>description here</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>description here</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription</key>
<string>description here</string>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you are looking for both English and Spanish, in which case you may have to consider using [nativescript-localize](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-localize#how-to-localize-ios-properties).